# How to create method without returning any value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a method where I can pass a float, evaluate it, then update a text label accordingly. Would someone be kind enough to take a look at my code and point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance...

```
public static GetGrade(float wp)
    {
        if (wp >= 100)
        {
            grade_current.Text = "A";
        }
        else if (wp >= 90)
        {
            grade_current.Text = "A";
        }
        else if (wp >= 75 && wp <= 89)
        {
            grade_current.Text = "B";
        }
        else if (wp >= 60 && wp <= 74)
        {
            grade_current.Text = "C";
        }
        else if (wp >= 50 && wp <= 59)
        {
            grade_current.Text = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            grade_current.Text = "F";
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call the method with `GetGrade(wp);`

Comment: You are not getting something from the function as return value. The function is doing something and returning void. So from the naming convention point of view it is better to remove Get from the function name.The function name could be SetGradeLabel etc. It would look more meaningful then.

Comment: Agreed, thank for you for the insightful reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use 'void', also you can clean up the code a bit to make it easier on the eyes:

```
public static void GetGrade(float wp)
{
    if (wp >= 100)
        grade_current.Text = "A";
    else if (wp >= 90)
        grade_current.Text = "A";
    else if (wp >= 75)
        grade_current.Text = "B";
    else if (wp >= 60)
        grade_current.Text = "C";
    else if (wp >= 50)
        grade_current.Text = "D";
    else
        grade_current.Text = "F";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting the following error when using this code: `Error 68 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property grade_current`

Comment: Because your method is static. To reference elements in your class try removing the 'static' as it doesn't seem needed here.  Simply use "public void GetGrade(float wp)"

Comment: Works great, looks much better now also! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is missing a return type. If you don't need to return anything then just use "`void`".

```
public static GetGrade(float wp)
```

=>

```
public static void GetGrade(float wp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and explanation. Working great now!